# How to search sharepoint document by a custom column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I am looking for a sharepoint rest api that I am able to use to search a column.

Document Id |  Title | Name | Address | Custom Field ....

Is there a way that I can find a sharepoint document by this custom field column?

Answer (score 2):

Column name searches are based on Crawled Properties. You cannot directly create or edit the Crawled Properties. They are added either by the Crawl Processors or automatically when you add Site Columns.

The basic steps to add a "custom column" that is column name searchable are:

- Add a new Site Column to the Site Collection. (Site Collection Admin)
- Add the new Site Column to at least one list or library. (Site Owner or Site Collection Admin)
- Add at least one item to the list or library with this field populated. This item must be checked in and published. (Site Owner or Site Collection Admin)
- Run an incremental crawl of the content, or wait until Office 365 / SharePoint Online runs its next index update. (Search Admin)

The searchable property name is "ugly" by default. If you have a Site Column named "Instructor", the Crawled Property will be named "ows_q_TEXT_Instructor" and the Managed Property will be named InstructorOWSTEXT. Your users can then search like this:

```
InstructorOWSTEXT:jones
```

Your Search Admin can edit the Managed Property and add an alias such as "Instructor" and the user can then search like this:

```
Instructor:jones
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/from-site-column-to-managed-propertywhat-s-up-with-that